# How to increase space for installing programs

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Noobie on 12.04. Sorry if this has been answered before but I have not been able to locate it.

I had Ubuntu and Windows installed together and then got rid of Windows. However, when I install programs they go into dev/sda1 and it is running out of room, while my newly created ext4 partition dev/sda2 is where all the memory sits (yes, I know, "all the memory" -- it is an old laptop). If I want to be able to install more programs, do I need to run gparted and resize partitions? Or is this an issue of "ownership" or using grub? Or something else? Here is what I look like:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0xbf2ebf2e

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *          63   101936392    50968165    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda2       101937150   117229567     7646209    5  Extended
    /dev/sda5       116203520   117229567      513024   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sda6       101937152   116203519     7133184   83  Linux
```

[image]

I want more space from `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sda6` which was my root partition.

Comment: upload the gparted screenshot to imgur.com and provide the link here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/YixmZDs

Comment: From the screenshot did you want more size for which partition and from where?

Comment: yes, more to sda6 from sda1, as it seems programs are installed in sda6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Gparted resize,delete only an unmounted partiion.So to resize the root partition you have to boot Ubuntu live disk.
- While booting from live-disk click on try Ubuntu option.
- Open gparted partition Editor from Dash.Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted.
- Now resize the `/dev/sda1` partition of space you want for `dev/sda6`.
- After resizing,an unallocated space was created just below to the `/dev/sda1`.
- Now right-click on the /dev/sda2 partition and click on Resize/Move option.Now drag the left arrow to the extreme left and then apply the changes.So that the unallocated space will come inside the extended partition.Now it comes just below to the `/dev/sda5`.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda5` partition and click on Resize/Move option,move the dragger to the extreme right,so that the unallocated space will comes just above to the `dev/sda5` linux-swap partition.
- Now you can be able to increase the size of `/dev/sda6` root partition.

Comment: Just a note for anyone actually in need, I had to download gparted and burn it as an iso and open it thus because when I opened gparted from the ubuntu live cd not all partitions were unmounted.

Comment: why you need a gparted iso file to make a bootable gparted disk,you can try gparted in ubuntu live disk.After booting the ubuntu live disk open gparted from dash and don't touch any partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a few days ago with a Kali Linux VM. I booted into a Live CD on the VM, unmounted the filesystem and was able to expand from there using gparted. As far as I know, unlike windows, it's not possible to expand a partition while in use.